# Unit testing DTS packages

Tags: unit-testing, dts

does anybody have any experience writing unit tests for sql server 2000 DTS packages?
I about to start working with DTS and jobs, so I want to be able to unit test as much as possible. I guess i could invoke dtsrun.exe via command line , but perhaps someone else has better ideas.

Thanks

Fede

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for insight but since no one else has given you ideas, I did come up with one that I will share.

In my case (I know not all cases), we use a lot of ActiveX (VBScript) scripts to accomplish things. I'm theorizing (I've not tried this) that, if I **move my ActiveX functionality to VBScript classes** that **I can unit test those classes** and etc. and then do very, very basic class instantiation and usage in the main function of the ActiveX script.

I've not tried to implement this; my project does not have the budget to do so. But, in theory it seems sound. I also am unaware of any challenges this may cause.

Please see [another question I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239494/unit-testing-for-vbscript-asp-code-and-sql-server-2000). The question is loosely related to yours. The answer I selected for this question doesn't fit your scenario. You'd be more interested in Michal's answer: [Creating unit tests for your asp application](http://www.ajaxed.org/article/Creating-unit-tests-for-your-asp-application/31/)

Answer (score 0):

Saw this question had been here for a while so I'm just throwing some ideas out there...

I'm wondering if you could write some code to use the [DTS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa176080%28SQL.80%29.aspx) to call your packages, then write assertions about those packages in the unit test tool for whatever language you used. For example, you could write your code in C# and use NUnit.

Additionally, if your DTS packages are all just calling SQL stored procedures, you can unit test the procedures (which would be true unit testing) using [T-SQL Unit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tsqlunit/).

If it's  higher level (integration) tests you want, then you might also consider hooking [FitNesse](http://fitnesse.org/) up to the DTS API.

Not sure if any of this helps, but I hope I've at least given you some ideas.